# Upload an Image with XMLHttpRequest (multipart/form-data)

Tags: image, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, uploader

i want to make an **Uploader** for a website.. i have used **Fiddler** to get information about the **Request**, i tried to make it.. everything is similar, i just don't know how to put the **image** in the request, i found some codes about how to do that with **HTMLRequest** but they didn't help me.. *This is my code :*

```
Const BOUNDARY = "----WebKitFormBoundary0IFvhsx4WYUNnJ1s"
        Dim strResponse, xmlhttp
        Dim strData
        strData = ""
        strData = strData & "--" & BOUNDARY & vbCrLf
        strData = strData & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""utf8""" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        strData = strData & "✓"
        strData = strData & vbCrLf
        strData = strData & "--" & BOUNDARY & vbCrLf
        strData = strData & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""authenticity_token""" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        strData = strData & "N+Om0R4Znca+WV/68i2kBRCHB5spBi+s5KIYMbG5/6c="
        strData = strData & vbCrLf
        strData = strData & "--" & BOUNDARY & vbCrLf
        strData = strData & "Content-Disposition:  form-data; name=""file""; filename=""img.png""" & vbCrLf
        strData = strData & "Content-Type: image/png" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        strData = strData & "The image should be here"
        xmlhttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://*/upload", False)
        xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8")
        xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4")
        xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
        xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader("User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36")
        xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & BOUNDARY)
        xmlhttp.Send(strData)
        If xmlhttp.readyState = 4 Then
            strResponse = xmlhttp.responseText
            MsgBox(strResponse)
        End If
```

If you know how to do it, please help me i will be grateful, Thanks!

Comment: `Const`? `Dim`? Are you asking about the ActiveX version of XMLHttpRequest and using it from VBScript embedded in Classic ASP?

Comment: the code is in vb.net, i know how to use the XMLHttpRequest on it, but i didn't know how to upload images with it..